# How to implement a universal login system like Buxfer: Open Id, Facebook, Google, Aol, etc

Tags: c#, .net, openid, facebook, google-friend-connect

Any idea how Buxfer (Buxfer.com) would have implemented their universal login system?  Did they use Facebook Connect and Google Friend Connect? I'm trying to implement one for my site using .NET C#, but I couldn't find any .NET client libraries for Google Connect.  But I was curious how Buxfer managed to let users sign in with not only Facebook and Google accounts, but also others like Yahoo, AOL, Microsoft, and Open ID.

Answer (score 2):

Buxfer.com uses different protocols,

1. They use OpenID for AOL, Google, of course OpenID login.
2. Facebook Connect is used for Facebook.
3. bbAuth for Yahoo
4. LiveId for Microsoft

All the flows are very similar and most ID providers also provide libraries so it's not that hard to implement all of them for a web site.

You can look into rpxnow.com as others mentioned if you don't want deal with multiple protocols.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question, but an easy solution I have used (without needing to worry about OpenID, OAuth, and what-they-all-are-called-today details) is http://rpxnow.com/, works like a charm but is of course "hosted" sign-in

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.ohloh.net/p/dotnetopenauth) is one of the best libraries for adding OpenId support. It supports all the OpenId providers and a few variants. There are lots of examples included in their downloadable as well. You just add a reference to the dll and copy one of the samples depending on your architecture.

To get Live authentication, go get the SDK from: http://dev.live.com/liveid/

Answer (score 0):

I believe that they coded the libraries themselves.
However, you can easily implement OpenID and OAuth - I am sure that libraries exist for those - since AOL, Yahoo, Google, Facebook, LiveJournal, etc. all support OpenID or OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

use openid , they cover large number of providers.for facebook , use facebook library for .net and for openid use dotnet dotnetopenidauth library.

Answer (score 0):

For OpenID You can use [Javascript OpenID Selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/)